# Avoid extra matches from Regex_search

Tags: c++

Very new to the c++ regex libraries.

We are trying to parse a line

```
*10 abc
```

We want to parse/split this line into **only** two tokens:

```
10
abc
```

I have tried multiple things such as regex_search but I do get 3 matches. First match is whole match and second, third are sub sequences matches. My question would be that

How can we get only two matches(10 & abc) from above string. Snapshot of what I have tried:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const std::string t = "*10 abc";
  std::regex rgxx("\\*(\\d+)\\s+(.+)");
  std::smatch match;
  bool matched1 = std::regex_search(t.begin(), t.end(), match, rgxx);
  std::cout << "Matched size " << match.size() << std::endl;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < match.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i << " match " << match[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Matched size 3
0 match *10 abc
1 match 10
2 match abc
```

0 match is the one which I do not want.

I am open to use boost libraries/regexes as well. Thank you.

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for such a simple parse. Just skip the first character, copy up to the first instance of whitespace, skip the whitespace, and copy the rest. With proper use of `std::string` that's only about four lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing really wrong with your code per se.  The zero match is just the entire string, which matched the regex pattern.  If you only want the two captured terms, then just print the first and second capture groups:

```
const std::string t = "*10 abc";
std::regex rgxx("(\\d+)\\s+(.+)");
std::smatch match;
bool matched1 = std::regex_search(t.begin(), t.end(), match, rgxx);
std::cout << "Matched size " << match.size() << std::endl;

for (int i=1; i < match.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i << " match " << match[i] << std::endl;
}

Matched size 3
1 match 10
2 match abc
```

So, the lesson here is that the first entry in the match array (index of zero) will always be the entire string.

Comment: I know that lesson as I have mentioned earlier. I want to know is there any way to not get entire string in the match array?

Comment: Not that I know of, as this is how the API works.  But, I don't think there is much of a performance penalty.  Rather, the capture groups is where the regex API would likely have to do more work.